# How to prevent downloading HTML/text pages as .png

Tags: python

http://puu.sh/3Krct.png

My program generates random links to a service that hosts images, and it grabs and downloads random images. The program makes a lot of requests, and so it has to go through proxies.

Well, when the program is started, I just give it the path to a fresh large proxy list; however, sometimes the proxies will not connect to the website and sometimes they will return a custom HTML page - OR the image service will return the message on the page "You don't have permission to view this image." Although, the program will still save the request and download the page with a .png extension

And so sometimes those HTML/text pages are saved as .png files:

http://puu.sh/3KrxM.png

http://puu.sh/3KrGN.png

Is there any way I can prevent the downloading of these pages, and only download the actual images?

Thank you.

```
if self.proxy != False:
    #make our requests go through proxy
    self.opener.retrieve(url, filename)
else:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: So you're having trouble scraping images from websites that don't belong to you by guessing at filenames and hiding behind multiple proxies?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hacking.

Comment: @msw The images are public. So it's not hacking. If they wanted to, they could make it private.

Comment: @msw I laughed quite hard when I read that comment. The purpose of this program is: a) gain knowledge in python b) when a competition against my friend (find the funniest/weirdest picture).

Comment: @msw I'm only using proxies so I can boost the speed of the program. I'm not doing it to be anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the logic.

If a proxy returns an error getting the page you asked, it normally uses an HTTP Status Code != 200

You should then check in order:

- The HTTP status != 200
- The Content-type header returned for the correct type (in this case image/jpeg)

And for this type of tasks I suggest using the [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: That still wouldn't really help the situation. Sometimes the image page will return a plain text page saying "You don't have permission to view this image." - I'd still need a method to prevent downloading that?

Comment: Oh that's true. Well then you have to check the content-type header. If returnstatus is 200 and content-type: image/jpeg then it's ok

Comment: I didn't think urllib.request.urlretrieve() returned content-type?

Comment: it should. But i suggest you to use python-requests package. Is the defacto standard on url retrieving. :)